# Validation to prevent double booking or overlapping when form submit

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a gown rental web app built with apps script and I need to add form validation to prevent double booking or overlapping of booking. If new booking entry for the same Rental Type and date will fall within the existing booking from Pick Up date and return date. Thank you.

```
function checkBookingOverlap(rentalType, pickUpDate, returnDate) {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Booking Data");
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 5, dataSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3); // Assuming rental type in column E, pick-up date in column F, and return date in column G
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    var existingRentalType = dataValues[i][0];
    var existingPickUpDate = new Date(dataValues[i][1]);
    var existingReturnDate = new Date(dataValues[i][2]);
    if (existingRentalType === rentalType &&
        ((pickUpDate >= existingPickUpDate && pickUpDate < existingReturnDate) ||
        (returnDate > existingPickUpDate && returnDate <= existingReturnDate) ||
        (pickUpDate <= existingPickUpDate && returnDate >= existingReturnDate))) {
      return true; // Overlap detected, booking not allowed
    }
  }
  return false; // No overlap found, booking allowed
}
```

HTML FORM

```
  <form class="row" id="bookingForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="rentalType" class="form-label">Rental Type</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="rentalType" name="rentalType" required>
          <option value="">Select Rental Type</option>
          <option value="Gown">Gown</option>
          <option value="Suit">Suit</option>
          <option value="Coat">Coat</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="pickUpDate" class="form-label">Pick Up Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="pickUpDate" name="pickUpDate" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="returnDate" class="form-label">Return Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="returnDate" name="returnDate" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label for="proofOfPayment" class="form-label">Proof of Payment</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="proofOfPayment" name="proofOfPayment" required>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label for="idProof" class="form-label">ID Proof</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="idProof" name="idProof" required>
 </div>
      <div class="col-12 text-center mt-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Booking</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your Google Apps Script (The function `checkBookingOverlap`) and HTML, and your current issue. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, the checkBookingOverlap apparently not working. That code is in my server side to check existing booking in my google sheets. I want a function on the client side to detect if the submission will overlap or duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I couldn't still understand the relationship between your Google Apps Script (The function `checkBookingOverlap`) and HTML, and your current issue. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Please disregard that function. My desired output is, on new form submission, check if the date will overlap to existing booking for the same Rental Type or if its a duplicate booking. I'm hoping to create a form validation for it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Thank you for your support. From your reply, I would like to try to imagine your actual situation. When I could correctly imagine it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Incorporate a script tag within your HTML code and implement validation logic within a designated function. Additionally, to execute a server-side function from the client side, utilize the google.script.run functionality. For detailed guidance, refer to: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: @ab.it.gcp I would think it would be better to perform that function within the handleFormSubmit function like the op is suggesting

Comment: What's your question? I only see a statement of requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function checkBookingOverlap(rtype, rpu, rrt) {
  const rpuv = justTheDate(rpu).value;
  const rrtv = justTheDate(rrt).value;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Booking Data");
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 5, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 3); // Assuming rental type in column E, pick-up date in column F, and return date in column G
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var stype = vs[i][0];
    var spuv = justTheDate(new Date(vs[i][1])).value;
    var srtv = justTheDate(new Date(vs[i][2])).value;
    if (rtype === stype &&
        ((rpuv >= spuv && rpuv < srtv) ||
        (rrtv > spuv && rrtv <= srtv))) {
      return true; // Overlap detected, booking not allowed
    }
  }
  return false; // No overlap found, booking allowed
}


function justTheDate(dt) {
  let d = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate());
  return {date: d, value: d.valueOf() }; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Cooper. It worked, I just modified your code a little and implement it directly to my handleFormSubmit function. Thank you kindly Sir.